# iPhone 5s - receiving sound notifications at random times with no alerts, emails, ims, etc

Tags: iphone, audio, notifications

Just recently when I take turn off vibrate om my iPhone, it has been playing alert sounds at random times without showing any notifications, no new emails, calls, texts, app updates, etc. It's really bizarre and makes me wonder if the phone is hacked.

While sending a text I even got the sound of a message being sent while I was in the middle of typing, I wasn't waiting on any other message to go out, nor were any message rejected that could potentially have gone through at a later time. Again, while on vibrate mode there are no phantom vibrations, it's only when the ringer is on.

Is there any way to tell if the phone has been hacked?

I'd really like to avoid resetting my phone if at all possible, I have something like 6,000 photos on it and lots of stuff that I cannot afford to lose.

Comment: Did you find out what was causing that problem? I have exactly the same with my 4s. But sounds are being played only when the screen is locked. Once in a week I receive sound with sms / e-mail but after unlocking I see no new incoming messages.

Answer (score 1):

One application you have, you set to not show any notifications, and just play sound. Go to Settings>Notifications. In the 'INCLUDE' list, disregard all that already show notifications. Check out the notification settings for the other applications. One of them is set to notify only by sound.